# User mutual friend ship checking laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in laravel v4.2 project and now I don't understand that how I make relashion to solve this issue.
I have an array of users and and login user id now I want to check that either login user is following to anyone of user in array either any single user of array is following to login user. Either one of then is following and both array following to each other then it return true. But I want to this problem througn laravel relashionship.
Below is my code that I code

```
$login_id = 2;

$users_arr = Array
(
    [0] => 87
    [1] => 9595
    [2] => 8625
    [3] => 18368
    [4] => 18363
    [5] => 18371
)

    class User extends Eloquent  {

            protected $table = 'users';
            protected $primaryKey = 'id';
            protected $guarded = array();
            protected $hidden = array();

        public function mutual_friends() {
           return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'friends', 'follower_id', 'following_id');
        }


        public static function get_users_infomation_by_ids($login_id, $users_arr = array()) {
            $users = User::where(function($sql) use($login_id, $users_arr) {
                        $sql->whereIn('id', $users_arr);
                    })->with(['mutual_friends'=>function($sql) use($login_id){
                        $sql->where('follower_id','=',$login_id);
                        $sql->orWhere('following_id','=',$login_id);
                    }])->get(array('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'is_live', 'message_privacy', 'picture'));
            return (!empty($users) && count($users) > 0) ? $users->toArray() : array();
        }
   }
```

friends table contail following columns `{id,follower_id,following_id}`

Now I want that any single condition is true then function return true with user information.

OutPut

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 87
            [username] => rizwan.saleem
            [full_name] => Rizwan Saleem
            [is_live] => 0
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => vmiboiagcropped-5589294861513766548.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => yahoo
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [following_id] => 87
                                    [follower_id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8625
            [username] => hassan_shahid
            [full_name] => Hassan Shahids
            [is_live] => 0
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => profile_default.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => yahoo
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [following_id] => 8625
                                    [follower_id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9595
            [username] => majo
            [full_name] => Majo mike
            [is_live] => 1
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => rwls1p2jcropped507977901504873847.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => yahoo
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [following_id] => 9595
                                    [follower_id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18363
            [username] => asif_ilsa
            [full_name] => Asif Ilsa 
            [is_live] => 1
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => ydi1dmtdupload-image1512648978.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18368
            [username] => ali.abbas
            [full_name] => Ali Abbas 1
            [is_live] => 1
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => dsczoljfcropped4868760551505544665.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => yahoo
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [following_id] => 18368
                                    [follower_id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18371
            [username] => maju
            [full_name] => Mani Dude
            [is_live] => 0
            [message_privacy] => 2
            [picture] => ndtcihu7upload-image1503915762.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [username] => yahoo
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [following_id] => 18371
                                    [follower_id] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

In above outpu id->18363 has no mutual record this is just because this
user not following login user even the login user following this user.

Comment: whats the problem??

Comment: @Sohel0415 problem is that suppose 2 user following 4 and 4 also following 2 and there is another user 5 following 2 but 2 not following 5 so when I fetch user information of 4 and 5 then I also need friends relashion informtion with user 2
login user = 2
Array(4,5)

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', $users_arr)
       ->with('mutual_friends')
       ->where(function ($query)  use ($login_id){
            $query->whereRaw('users.id=friends.follower_id OR users.id=friends.following_id')->where(function($q) use ($login_id){
              $q->where('follower_id',$login_id);
           });
        })
       ->get(array('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'is_live', 'message_privacy', 'picture'));
```

Comment: it returns friends informtion of those users whose following each other or only login user mean 2 user following but if another is following to login user but login user not following then it return empty

Comment: @RizwanSaleem include all ids that you want to get in `$users_arr`, may be you are missing some ids here

Comment: Login User = 2
Array
(
    [0] => 19071
    [1] => 87
    [2] => 9595
    [3] => 8625
    [4] => 18368
    [5] => 18363
    [6] => 18371
)
in array user every user has friends information but only 18363 user has no friends information because loign user not following to this user but this user following to login user

Comment: so what you are getting now and what is your expectation?

Comment: my expection is that it return friends information if both are following each other or if any one of them following to other
But I am get if both are following to each other or only login user following to other user then I receive friends information

Comment: could you please update your question with some sample data, what you are getting now and what do you expect?? And provide data of `$users_arr` and `$login_id`

Comment: I update my question with more explanation and sample data

Comment: it return this with all records 
 [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                )
after implementing new solution

Comment: giving empty or giving everything??

Comment: empty with all records

Comment: seems we need to use raw sql query, i will update my answer, what is your table name in database?? related to this query

Comment: @RizwanSaleem try my answer now

Comment: i have implemented your answer now its return all the following list each user instead of exact matching condition with login user

Comment: what do you really want?? Do you want the records associate with login user only ?? Or everything??

Comment: with login user only

Comment: have a look now make a quick try please

Comment: still receiving this result even this user following login user
Array
        (
            [id] => 18363
            [username] => asif_ilsa
            [full_name] => Asif Ilsa 
            [is_live] => 1
            [message_privacy] => 0
            [picture] => ydi1dmtdupload-image1512648978.jpg
            [mutual_friends] => Array
                (
                )

        )

Comment: @RizwanSaleem updated again, try now, everything has been fixed, please make a quick try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163413/discussion-between-rizwan-saleem-and-sohel0415).